# Установить параметры в СКД

Tags: 1с

Добрый день. Создаю отчет на СКД, который вызывается из формы обработки. В отчет нужно установить параметры, знаю что, если делать через стандартную форму отчета - 
это происходит так:

```
 П = КомпоновщикНастроек.Настройки.ПараметрыДанных.Найти("Параметр");  
 П.Значение = Значение;
 П.Использование = Истина;
```

но в данном случае у меня еще нет КомпановщикаНастроек и мне необходимо создать его вручную, вопрос как это сделать и в какой из конструкоров он должен передаться?
Код:

```
ТабличныйДокумент = Новый ТабличныйДокумент;

    СхемаКомпоновкиДанных = Обработки.ВР_АктСверкиВзаиморасчетовПачкой.ПолучитьМакет("Макет");

    Настройки = СхемаКомпоновкиДанных.НастройкиПоУмолчанию;

    ДанныеРасшифровки = Новый ДанныеРасшифровкиКомпоновкиДанных;

    КомпоновщикМакета = Новый КомпоновщикМакетаКомпоновкиДанных;

    МакетКомпоновки = КомпоновщикМакета.Выполнить(СхемаКомпоновкиДанных,
                                        Настройки, ДанныеРасшифровки);

    ПроцессорКомпоновкиДанных = Новый ПроцессорКомпоновкиДанных;
    ПроцессорКомпоновкиДанных.Инициализировать(МакетКомпоновки,,
                                                   ДанныеРасшифровки);

    ПроцессорВывода = Новый ПроцессорВыводаРезультатаКомпоновкиДанныхВТабличныйДокумент;
    ПроцессорВывода.УстановитьДокумент(ТабличныйДокумент);

    ПроцессорВывода.Вывести(ПроцессорКомпоновкиДанных);

    ТабличныйДокумент.Показать();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
КомпоновщикНастроек = Новый КомпоновщикНастроекКомпоновкиДанных();
КомпоновщикНастроек.Инициализировать(Новый ИсточникДоступныхНастроекКомпоновкиДанных(СхемаКомпоновкиДанных)); 
// Это берёт настройки по умолчанию из вашей СКД
// без этого компоновщик настроек будет пустым 
КомпоновщикНастроек.ЗагрузитьНастройки(СхемаКомпоновкиДанных.НастройкиПоУмолчанию);
Настройки = КомпоновщикНастроек.Настройки;

// настраиваете все ваши настройки
// ...

// Передаёте настройки компоновщику макета.
МакетКомпоновки = КомпоновщикМакета.Выполнить(СхемаКомпоновкиДанных, Настройки, ДанныеРасшифровки);
```

В принципе можно обойтись и без компоновщика настроек:

```
Настройки = СхемаКомпоновкиДанных.НастройкиПоУмолчанию;
/////// Делаете настройки
// Передаёте настройки компоновщику макета.
МакетКомпоновки = КомпоновщикМакета.Выполнить(СхемаКомпоновкиДанных, Настройки, ДанныеРасшифровки);
```

Comment: @mantigatos, спасибо!